# Could not find stored procedures in SQL Server, IIS 6 server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have an application that is running an calls a stored procedure. This application works fine on another PC connecting to a database, but not on localhost. The database was backed up and restored on my dev computer. The source code is exactly the same thus there is no naming/typo error.

When I run the app, I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure 'xyz'.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)

I know the application is connecting to the database properly as it has already logged into the database.

What I have tried:

- grant all permissions to the db_user(I have made the db_user the owner of the database and granted all permissions of the stored procedure to the user)
- ran `aspnet_regiis` to configure the application on the SQL Server.

However, it seems like I am still getting the error.

Any advise will be greatly appreciated. I have googled the rest of the similar could not find stored procedure on stackoverflow, but none of the resolutions worked.

Comment: Did you check the schema? Is the procedure in `dbo`? Is the default schema for the calling user `dbo`? Did you try specifying `dbo.xyz` instead of just `xyz`? How do you know the user is calling the procedure in the context of the right database? (You don't really log in to a database, and you can change the context as often as you want once logged in.) There's also a chance you're not connecting to the copy of the database you think you are - does your connection string use `AttachDbFileName`?

Comment: Hi aaron, thanks for your advise. My procedure is in a schema called dbb and my user is mapped to that schema,

How do you know the user is calling the procedure in the context of the right database? - the connection is done through the web.config file,   <add key="DB_CONNECT" value="Data Source=SPXXX;Initial Catalog=eddDB;"/>  and from there, I call the connectionstring

Comment: Try `EXEC eddDB.dbb.xyz;` instead of `EXEC xyz;`.